# C#, PhotonServer. When I Start a Photon Instance, always occurred an Error. Not about the port, it's the config file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Every time I open the file, PhotonServer.config, with VS2017, as long as I change the configuration, then PhotonServer can't start. It always occurrs an Error like this.

```
4400: 02:48:14.196 - Config File:D:\Photon-OnPremise-Server-SDK_v4-0-29-11263\deploy\bin_Win64\PhotonServer.config
4400: 02:48:14.196 - CService::OnException()-Exception:CXMLDocument::LoadFromString() - Error document empty.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGLsP.png)

Even if I change PhotonServer.config back, it still occurrs same Error. Seems like the VS Change the End Of Line. Then I change the End Of Line to LF, but I still can't fix it.

After that, I roll back PhotonServer.config, and I used another text editor to config the file, same change. Then it worked...

Can anybody tell me why? Is that the VS change something? It puzzled me for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

HuJF

I think VS removes the old file and creates the new one during saving and photon just manages to read it before VS fills it with content

best,
Photonians

Comment: Thanks so much. But it doesn't make sense that when I used VS change the file PhotonServer.config, the Photon Server still can check the configuration. It just can't work.

However, Thank u so much~

Comment: I see what you mean. You are probably right that it breaks line endings which expected to be standard windows \r\n
We just did not face such issues before

best,
Photonians